# Gradle shadow plugin packages also all "provided" dependencies which should not be the case

Tags: gradle

I want to have one fat jar but without the provided dependencies. So I use the following two plugins:

- https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow
- https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-extra-configurations-plugin

and have a build.gradle file like this:

```
apply plugin: 'nebula.provided-base'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

archivesBaseName = 'range-cache-drivers'
group = 'com.engine'
version = '0.302-SNAPSHOT'

buildDir = 'target'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8


dependencies {
    provided project(':rangeCache')

    // CSV, TSV, Fixe width
    compile deps.univocityParsers
    // MongoDB
    compile deps.mongo
    // Cassandra
    compile deps.cassandradx
    compile deps.cassandraSnappy
    compile deps.cassandraLZ4
}
```

But when I run `gradle shadowJar` I still have all the rangeCache classes in my fat jar. How can I exclude the provided dependencies from my fat jar?

EDIT 1:
This seems also not to work, the transient dependencies still getting copied into the fat jar.

```
shadowJar {
    dependencies {
        exclude(project(':rangeCache'))
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: Based on Stanislav's answer I did the following to get things working properly:

```
configurations {
    shadow
    compile.extendsFrom provided
    provided.extendsFrom shadow
}

dependencies {
    provided project(':rangeCache')

    // CSV, TSV, Fixe width
    shadow deps.univocityParsers

    // MongoDB
    shadow deps.mongo

    // Cassandra
    shadow deps.cassandradx
    shadow deps.cassandraSnappy
    shadow deps.cassandraLZ4

    testCompile deps.junit
}

import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

task fatJar(type: ShadowJar) {
    configurations = [project.configurations.shadow]
    from(project.sourceSets.main.output)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20180725204142/http://unethicalblogger.com/2015/07/15/gradle-goodness-excluding-depends-from-shadow.html) about excluding shadow jar dependencies.

Shortly, according to this article, just excluding some dependency via `shadowJar`'s dependencies is not enough for excluding its transitive dependencies, just as you mentioned already. The solution how to do it is to modify runtime configuration, to exclude from it some dependency, like:

```
configurations {    
    runtime.exclude %what you need to exclude%
}
```

I Hope, it could be helpful.

Comment: This dows not work with projects. However I went for the solution number 3 in the linked blog post which is working quite well